# ModelState Errors always showing in English in Azure Web Role

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, localization

I´m having problems with model validation errors in a ASP.NET WebApi deployed in Azure.

This is the code that returns ModelState Errors:

```
public static class ComprobarErroresModelo
{
    public static string GetErrors(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var result = "";
        foreach (var error in modelState.Values.SelectMany(value => value.Errors))
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage))
                result = result + error.Exception.Message + '\n';
            else
                result = result + error.ErrorMessage + '\n';
        return result;
    }
}
```

In global.asax I have tried several modifications over this:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es");

        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es");
    }

    void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es");

        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es");
    }
```

But none of them works in Azure, I always get ModelState errors in English

I have tested in local environment changing "es" to "en" and it works ok, but in Azure it always shows English message errors

How can I get ModelState errors in spanish or other language in Azure Web Role??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BaseController`, that has the culture set while it's initialized, and make all your API controllers inherit from it instead of `ApiController` directly:

```
public abstract class BaseController : ApiController
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        var culture = new CultureInfo("es");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it´s not working in Azure. In localhost works ok :(